# MySQL: JOINs on 1-to-1 basis

Tags: mysql, sql, join, relationship, relationships

I think, this problem is of more advanced SQL category (MySQL in this case): I have two tables (`TABLE_FRUIT`, `TABLE_ORIGIN` - just example names) which have columns that can be joined (`fruit_name`).

Consider the following diagram:

```
TABLE_FRUIT
fruit_id|fruit_name  |variety
--------|----------------------
       1|Orange      |sweet
       2|Orange      |large
       3|Lemon       |wild
       4|Apple       |red
       5|Apple       |yellow
       6|Pear        |early
etc...

TABLE_ORIGIN
fuit_id  |fruit_name|Origin
---------|----------|--------
        1|Apple     | Italy
        2|Pear      | Portugal
        3|Grape     | Italy
        4|Orange    | Spain
        5|Orange    | Portugal
        6|Orange    | Italy
etc...      



Desired Result:     
TABLE_FRUIT_ORIGIN
fuit_id  |fruit_name|Origin
---------|----------|--------
        1|Orange    | Spain
        2|Orange    | Portugal
        3|Apple     | Italy
        4|Pear      | Portugal
```

The tables have multiple identical values in columns that compose the joins(`fruit_name`). Despite that, I need to join the values on 1-to-1 basis. In other words, there is "Orange" value 2 times in `TABLE_FRUIT` and 3 times in `TABLE_ORIGIN`. I am looking for a result of two matches, one for Spain, one for Portugal. Italy value from `TABLE_ORIGIN` must be ignored, because there is no available third Orange value in `TABLE_FRUIT` to match Orange value in `TABLE_ORIGIN`.

I tried what I could, but I can not find anything relevant on Google. For example, I tried adding one more column `record_used` and tried `UPDATE` but without success.

```
TABLE_ORIGIN
    fuit_id  |fruit_name|origin     |record_used
    ---------|----------|-----------|-----------
            1|Apple     | Italy     |
            2|Pear      | Portugal  |
            3|Grape     | Italy     |
            4|Orange    | Spain     |
            5|Orange    | Portugal  |
            6|Orange    | Italy     |
    etc...      




UPDATE
    TABLE_FRUIT t1
INNER JOIN
    TABLE_ORIGIN t2
ON
    (t1.fruit_name = t2.fruit_name)
AND
    (t2.record_used IS NULL)
SET
    t2.record_used = 1;
```

**Summary:**

- Find matching records between two tables on 1-to-1 basis (probably JOIN)
- For each record in `TABLE_FRUIT` find just one (next first) matching record in `TABLE_ORIGIN`
- If a record in `TABLE_ORIGIN` was already matched once with a record from `TABLE_FRUIT`, it may not be considered again in the same query run.

Comment: Before you do anything, I suggest you fix your table structure and data.  In TABLE_FRUIT, why would you have 2 records that are Orange, and 2 records that are Apple.  How would you identify which Orange from TABLE_FRUIT should join to which Orange from TABLE_ORIGIN?  The messed up table structure will only give you messed up join.  This is not one-to-one relationship.  This is many-to-many relationship.

Comment: as well as what Eric says, you also should not use the name 'Fruit_ID' (albeit misspelled) in both tables if it means different things... and if this isn't the primary key, why does it exist at all?

Comment: Hi @Eric, @JeffUK, I have added a bit clarity to the table `TABLE_FRUIT`. Now it might explain, why I use Orange and other fruit mulitple times. It his how my input data is structured, There are excel tables having many columns 30+ and over 100.000 rows. I need to match the data with another tables. These are reports generated from large and expensive systems. Unfortunately, I do not think, I can do anything to change how the data is delivered. I want to find solution for the data as delivered.

Comment: @Eric, I do not need to precisely identify which Orange. The goal here is to identify if there is enough Oranges in `TABLE_ORIGIN` and to assign one ID from `TABLE_ORIGIN` to `TABLE_FRUIT`.

Comment: You can select RANK from both tables for each item, fruit and origin and then join them to match it.

Comment: @Bunkai.Satori In your desired result above, why isn't there a record with Orange and Italy?

Comment: @Eric, good question. Oranges is not there because that was the assignment I received. I have to combine values from both excel tables on one-to-one basis. If I take one Oranges record from `TABLE_FRUIT` I have to match it to one Oranges record in 'TABLE_ORIGIN'. I may use Oranges only once in matching process. If there are records for matching missing in either table, in this case, there are only two Oranges in `TABLE_FRUIT`, there is no matching record. As the result of this, we have only two matches.

Comment: Hi @clinomaniac. This is probably very good tip from you. I will take a look at RANK, as it is not known to me in MySQL. Thank you very much for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I had in mind with RANK function. After commenting, I realized mysql doesn't have a built in RANK over GROUP BY function so had to find this work around.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT fruit_name, 
               @f_rank := IF(@f_name = fruit_name, @f_rank + 1, 1) AS rank, 
               @f_name := fruit_name 
        FROM   table_fruit 
        ORDER  BY fruit_name DESC) f 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT fruit_name, 
                          @f_rank := IF(@f_name = fruit_name, @f_rank + 1, 1) AS 
                          rank, 
                          @f_name := fruit_name 
                   FROM   table_origin 
                   ORDER  BY fruit_name DESC) o 
               ON f.fruit_name = o.fruit_name 
                  AND f.rank = o.rank;
```

Explanation: Rank each item in the table for each fruit. So Orange in the first table would have rank 1 and 2 and so will Apple. In the second table, Orange will have rank 1, 2 and 3 but others will only have rank 1. Then when joining the tables based on names, you can also join based on rank so that way, you'll get Orange rank 1 and 2 match but Orange with rank 3 will not match.

This is based on my understanding of the problem. Let me know if the requirement is something different than what I have given here.

Comment: fyi: MySQL V8 (when released) is due to have those functions.

Comment: @Used_By_Already Good to know. Always bothered me as to why it doesn't have these kind of functions.

Comment: Agree! It has been slow to catch-up. (ps Glad you did the @variable approach - I was about to when I saw you had.)

Comment: @clinomaniac, seemingly, you are really skilled. Firstly, you realized, that my question is regarding MySQL and not SQL. Then, when I read your comment above, I wished, I would know more about RANK.  I scrolled down and found this answer from you. You even understood my question well. From what I read in your answer, it looks exactly like the solution. I need to assign individual fruit types to each other from both tables, as long as there is what to assign. If we run out of the fruit on either side, we move to the next fruit. I will take a closer look at this, when I get home. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is an arbitrary relationship between the number of entries and the order of those entries, so use techniques to match the number of items and order of those items. In MariaDB v10 which supports "window functions" `dense_rank()` and `row_number()` this is relatively easy:

> ```
> select 
>        row_number() over(order by fn.fruit_id) as fruit_id
>       , fn.fruit_name, o.Origin, fn.variety
> from (
>      select fruit_name, variety, fruit_id
>           , dense_rank() over(partition by fruit_name order by fruit_id) rnk
>      from table_fruit
>     ) fn
> inner join (
>      select fruit_name, Origin
>           , dense_rank() over(partition by fruit_name order by fruit_id) rnk
>      from table_origin
>     ) o on fn.fruit_name = o.fruit_name and fn.rnk = o.rnk
> ```
>
> ```
> fruit_id | fruit_name | Origin   | variety
> -------: | :--------- | :------- | :------
>        1 | Orange     | Spain    | sweet  
>        2 | Orange     | Portugal | large  
>        3 | Apple      | Italy    | red    
>        4 | Pear       | Portugal | early
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=7f6df06d46e2e96bc75c3bae0f343bba)*

A pure MySQL solution is a bit more complex because it requires use of @variables that will substitute for those window functions.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Excellent information. Firstly, "Arbitrary Relationship" sounds exactly like what my question is about. I will study this topic. And yes, your result is what I want to achieve. As I use MySQL, I have to apply your example from MariaDB to MySQL. However, clinomaniac, has provided me with great answer just below, which uses MySQL. Thank you for finding time for me.