# MySQL: How to do a query with a limit for each WHERE filter

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to do a query filtered by IDs, but I need to limit the results for each ID. I don't know how to do this in one query, I can only do it looping each ID with PHP, doing a query for each iteration, then merge the results together:

```
$allResults = [];
$ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

foreach ($ids as $id) {

    $db->query("
        SELECT *
        FROM example_table
        WHERE example_id = $id
        ORDER BY rating DESC
        LIMIT 2
    ");
    $results = $db->getResults();

    $allResults = array_merge($allResults, $results);
}
```

The above does what I need, but how would I do this in one query instead of a loop of 5 queries?

I'm looking for something like this:

```
    SELECT *
    FROM example_table
    WHERE 
        example_id = 1 LIMIT 2 OR
        example_id = 2 LIMIT 2 OR
        example_id = 3 LIMIT 2 OR
        example_id = 4 LIMIT 2 OR
        example_id = 5 LIMIT 2
    ORDER BY rating DESC
```

Obviously the limit in the where clause throws an error, but you can see what I'm trying to achieve. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Easy. But see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: You can do that using a rank and limit on the rank function. Take hints from this https://stackoverflow.com/a/47933641/3179169 and then you can select the rank based on id and finally select items that have a rank <= 2.

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but you are closing your `$db->query` function with a `}` rather than a `)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Strawberry mentioned, its hard to give proper answer without verifiable example and data but this is what the query might look like since mysql doesn't support group rank functions yet.

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT *, 
    @f_rank := IF(@f_rating = rating AND @f_id = id, @f_rank + 1, 1) AS rank, 
    @f_rating := rating,
    @f_id := id
FROM   example_table 
WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
ORDER  BY id, rating DESC) tmp_table
WHERE tmp_table.rank <= 2
```

What you need to do here is rank all the ratings from 1 to n for each id. And then select the top two ids.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following UNION query:

```
(SELECT * FROM example_table WHERE id = 1 ORDER BY rating DESC LIMIT 2)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM example_table WHERE id = 2 ORDER BY rating DESC LIMIT 2)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM example_table WHERE id = 3 ORDER BY rating DESC LIMIT 2)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM example_table WHERE id = 4 ORDER BY rating DESC LIMIT 2)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM example_table WHERE id = 5 ORDER BY rating DESC LIMIT 2)
```

Here is one way how to create it in PHP:

```
$ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

$sqlArray = array_map(function($id){
    $id = (int)$id;
    return "(SELECT * FROM example_table WHERE id = $id ORDER BY rating DESC LIMIT 2)";
}, $ids);

$sql = implode("\nUNION ALL\n", $sqlArray);
```

Demo: http://rextester.com/GNDR46232

You should also consider to prepare the query with placeholders and bind the ids. Since I don't know the class of `$db` here is the PDO method:

```
$ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

$sqlArray = array_map(function($id){
    return "(SELECT * FROM example_table WHERE id = ? ORDER BY rating DESC LIMIT 2)";
}, $ids);

$sql = implode("\nUNION ALL\n", $sqlArray);

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($ids);
$allResults = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little more complex than I thought it was going to be, but you should be able to create the query programatically in PHP fairly easily.  You can't even do a direct limit on a UNION, but you can effectively do a select on a select on a select with a limit at the lowest level.  Whether or not this is more efficient than doing 5 separate queries is unknown.

```
SELECT *
      FROM (SELECT *
            FROM example_table
            WHERE id = 1
            LIMIT 2) AS id1
      UNION
      SELECT *
      FROM (SELECT *
            FROM example_table
            WHERE id = 2
            LIMIT 2) AS id2
      UNION
      SELECT *
      FROM (SELECT *
            FROM example_table
            WHERE id = 3
            LIMIT 2) AS id3
      .... more UNIONS ....;
```

Comment: You don't need the outer select.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel you're right.  The first time I tried to write this it didn't compile and I thought that was it.  I'm editing the answer.

Answer (score 0):

(it's a bit confusing that you have an attribute named "id" which is not unique)

The union based approaches all mean hard coding the values for example_id in the query and don't scale well to large numbers of example_ids.

OTOH this will make for relatively efficient queries when only looking at a subset of the values.

Here's an alternative approach...

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT id, max(rating) as scndrt
FROM example_table scnd
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT id, max(rating) maxrt
   FROM example_table
   GROUP BY id) AS first
 ON scnd.id=first.id
 WHERE scnd.rating<first.maxrt
 ) AS rts
 INNER JOIN example_table thrd
 ON rts.id=thrd.id
 AND thrd.rating IN (rts.maxrt, rts.scndrt)
```

This has won't return IDs with only one record, will return more than 2 records if (for example) the top rating appears twice for an id. It also requires multiple passes through the data.

I think it may also be possible to address the original problem using variables in the query, something like....

```
 SELECT @rank:=1+IF(id=@previd, @rank, 0) as ranking,
 @previd=id AS currentid,
 FROM (
   SELECT *
   FROM example_table
   ORDER BY id, rating DESC
 ) AS src
 HAVING ranking<3
```

I've not tested using variables like this, so it's possible you would have to unroll the select above into a procedure using a [cursor](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cursors.html) and write the matching rows to a temporary table.

Comment: The UNION ALL approach *scales* linear to the number of ids.

Comment: No, it breaks when the query becomes larger than the max packet size and the cost of generating the plan increases non-linearly as the number of IDs increase. Even with linear increases it needs to execute multiple passes through the same data. It's also a pig to maintain with large numbers of ids, although your php generator helps